# Update CoordinateMatrix entry

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Is there an efficient way to update a value for a certain index (i,j) for CoordinateMatrix?
Currently I'm using map to iterate all values and update only when I find those certain indexes but I don't think this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. `CoordinateMatrix` is backed by and `RDD` and is immutable. Even if you optimize access by:

- Getting its `entries`:

  ```scala
  val mat: CoordinateMatrix = ???
  val entries = mat.entries
  ```
- Converting to `RDD` of `((row, col), value)` and hash partitioning.

  ```scala
  val n: Int = ???
  val partitioner = new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(n)
  val pairs = entries.map(e => ((e.i, e.j), e.value)).partitionBy(partitioner)
  ```
- Mapping only a single partition:

  ```scala
  def update(mat: RDD[((Long, Long), Double)], i: Long, j: Long, v: Double) = {
    val p = mat.partitioner.map(_.getPartition((i, j)))
    p.map(p => mat.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
      case (pi, iter) if pi == p => iter.map {
        case ((ii, jj), _) if ii == i && jj == j => ((ii, jj), v)
        case x => x
      }
      case (_, iter) => iter
    })

  }
  ```

you'll still make a new `RDD` for each update.